# Tox command failing with error "No pyproject.toml or setup.py file"

Tags: virtualenv, python-venv, tox, pyvenv

Tox command is failing using tox.ini

```
$ tox
ERROR: No pyproject.toml or setup.py file found.  The expected locations are:
 /home/test/sample/pyproject.toml or /home/test/sample/setup.py
You can
  1. Create one:
     https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/package.html
  2. Configure tox to avoid running sdist:
     https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/general.html
  3. Configure tox to use an isolated_build
```

**tox.ini**

```
[tox]
envlist = py310

[testenv]
commands =
    pytest
```